# How do I create variable defined for each object?

Tags: python

So I've been creating *Person* classes, which hold variables like *name* and *age*. I would then create multiple Person classes which have different variables unique to each class. What I want to add next is to give each Person a "relationship" variable shared between each of these classes.

For example:

> The relationship between George and Alex is -31.

How would I approach this? I've thought about just making a variable for each object, but this doesn't seem convenient when there's just too much Person classes in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm not sure you want to make each person a different class.  The idea behind classes is that a class describes a *type* of object (like a `Person`), and then each `Person` is an *instance* of that type of object (like George).

So if your Person class is like:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

then you might have:

```
george = Person("George", 20)
alex = Person("Alex", 22)
```

Both `george` and `alex` are instances of `Person`, not their own `class`.  This make sense so far?

Now, the way you'd add a relationship might be to have a dictionary that associates other `Person`s with this relationship score.  While we're at it, let's add a `__repr__` function to our class so we can pretty-print our people:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.relationships: Dict["Person", int] = {}

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "%s, age %d" % (self.name, self.age)
```

Now you can do:

```
george.relationships[alex] = -31
alex.relationships[george] = -31
```

If we print out George's relationships, we get:

```
>>> print(george.relationships)
{Alex, age 22: -31}
```

And you can do this regardless of how many people and how many relationships between them you want to model (a dictionary can hold an arbitrary number of values associated with an arbitrary number of keys, which in this case is a `Person` instance).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a person can have a "relationship" with more than one other person, you will need a dictionary to store all of the relationships that a person has. I suggest mapping the other person's name to the "relationship" number (-31 in your example).

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name
        self.relationships = dict()

    def set_relationship(self, other, value):
        self.relationships[other.name] = value
        other.relationships[self.name] = value

    def get_relationship(self, other):
        return self.relationships[other.name]

    def has_relationship(self, other):
        return other.name in self.relationships
```

The `set_relationships` method updates both objects' dictionaries, because the way you've described the relationship, it should be symmetric.

Usage:

```py
>>> alice = Person('alice')
>>> bob = Person('bob')
>>> clive = Person('clive')
>>> alice.set_relationship(bob, 12)
>>> alice.relationships
{'bob': 12}
>>> bob.get_relationship(alice)
12
>>> clive.has_relationship(alice)
False
```

If you genuinely need each person to be represented by a different class (instead of just objects of the same class), you can write your other classes as subclasses of `Person`. That way you won't have to duplicate the code above across many different classes.